# Easily add libraries to Eclipse Java Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

I know there are post about JAVA libraries in Eclipse and I used a way to add some .jar files (like apache.poi and jsoup) to my project. My question is:
Where do we have to put those libraries and what settings do we have to change, so to make the libraries available for every future project we start ? 
Thank you!

Comment: Dependencies are defined per project, not per IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common tools for bringing dependencies into a Java project are Maven, Gradle, and Ant. I'll focus on Maven, as I estimate it to be the most popular of the three (though I have come to prefer Gradle).

I'm going to assume you have the following prerequisites installed on your machine and each of the developers on your team:

- JDK 1.7 or above (in other words, Java)
- A Java-focused IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse

Here's what you need to do:

- You and your team members will install Maven
- You will create a `pom.xml` for each new project.
- You will specify the dependencies for the project (like jsoup) in your `pom.xml`

Here's what Maven will do for you:

- It will download all the dependencies you specify from an online repository like `https://mvnrepository.com/`
- It will cache the dependencies in a directory in your user home folder called `.m2` so that it doesn't need to download dependencies more than once per project
- It will resolve the dependencies within each of your dependencies and avoid putting the same dependency on the classpath twice

The minimum `pom.xml` file you need is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Copy that into a file called pom.xml in your root project directory. You can add any additional dependencies in the `<dependencies>` section of the XML file. By convention, all of *your* classes and code should go into the directory structure `src/main/java/`.

Any Java IDE you use will know how to open a project from a pom.xml file. In IntelliJ, you select `File->New->Project from existing sources`, navigate to your project's root directory, select your pom.xml, and click Open. IntelliJ will then open your project as a Maven project, read your pom.xml, and make all of your dependencies indexed and available for code completion and compilation.

Hope this helps